# visual stadio express 2015でローカルやエラー一覧タブをショートカットキーで切り替えたい

Tags: c#, visual-studio

マウス移動でタブを切り替えているのですが、
無駄な動作なのでできればショートカットキーを設定したいと思っております。
どこからキー設定を行えば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

各ウィンドウを表示するメニューに表示されているショートカットキーを使用すれば直接表示可能です。例えば私の環境(Visual C# 2005スキーム)では以下のキーにバインドされています。

- 「表示(V)/エラー一覧(I)」：Ctrl+W, E
- 「デバッグ(D)/ウィンドウ(W)/ローカル(L)」：Ctrl+D, L

なおショートカットキーを追加または変更したい場合「ツール(T)/オプション(O)...」の「環境/キーボード」で行います。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 自分なりにカスタマイズして
更に作業効率が上がりました。
ご回答ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

[方法: Visual Studio IDE 内で移動する](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/a96fx0b9.aspx)より

Ctrl + TAB / Ctrl + Shift + TABでActive Filesの切り替えができます。
Alt + F7 / Alt + Shift + F7でActive Tool Windowsの切り替えができます。

Comment: まさに求めていた内容でした。
これで作業効率が上がります。
ありがとうございます。